# How to import database Oracle from large sql files

Tags: oracle, import, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have an Oracle 11g database with many records and I export all tables and data via SQL Developer. The .sql file produced by the export is more than 2GB and when I always import the script with SQL Developer the process ends after 4 hours. Is there a way to import all tables with data in a better mode?

**Another question:** in all the tables there are foreign keys, could the insertion of the data generate errors if not done in a certain order? If yes, how do you handle this problem?

Comment: "Is there a way to import all tables with data in a better mode?" Yes, don't use SQL Developer to do the export/import. Use RMAN (or the `expdp` and `impdp` utilities) and create a backup of the database and then restore from the backup.

Comment: Thanks, I have to try this method and I'll tell you how it went

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem using SQL*Loader

[link](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-administration/oracle-sqlloader/)

Answer (score 4):

DO NOT OPEN THE FILE.

Instead, REFERENCE the file.

```
@file.sql -- run with F5
```

The easiest way to address circular references on foreign key when doing INSERTs, is to insert the data and THEN create/enable the keys.

An even better/easier route would be to use Data Pump to export and import your database. It'll scale much better than .SQL files.